# Search results page not inheriting from parent site

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, variations

I am using variations and have 2 sites under main:

Main Site

- English site
- French site

I created a search results page in English site as below and inserted search web parts.

```
http://myserver/en/Pages/Search.aspx
```

I have defined this search page in top level site which is Main Site under "Send queries to a custom results page URL"

When I search on Main Site then it shows my search result page which is fine.

Now in my English site and other sub sites Search settings, I have chosen option "Use the same results page settings as my parent" but in none of the sub sites it takes my to my custom search results page. And instead it always shows default search results page.

If I specifically define this search results URL under "Send queries to a custom results page URL" in all sub sites, only then it shows my search results page.

What am I doing wrong? I want to use this search results page for all sites or please give me another alternative to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found out I needed to set search setting in "Site Collection" which solved the problem.